# DynamoDB query to json

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, optimization, amazon-dynamodb

I have a web service which will need to query the dynamodb many times per second for items. The user will request items (multiple at a time) which will be be served by the database. The results I would preferably like to have returned using JSON. Reading the AWS documentation they provide an example with a collection of items which each item gets printed out using JSONPretty();

```
private static void findRepliesForAThread(String forumName, String threadSubject) {

    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);

    String replyId = forumName + "#" + threadSubject;

    QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
        .withKeyConditionExpression("Id = :v_id")
        .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
            .withString(":v_id", replyId));

    ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

    System.out.println("\nfindRepliesForAThread results:");

    Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next().toJSONPretty());
    }

}
```

If I now want to return all the items to a user I have to do what they did here which is loop through the item collection, concat all the items to a string to form a JSON and then send it back to client. I would like to skip the iteration if at all possible and allow this to happen on the client side. Is there any other way to query a table in dynamodb in which I do not have to go through iterations on the server side, but can just return readable results back to the client and the processing of items can happen there? I am not fixed on using JSON and open to anything else which would allow me to eliminate an iteration of items. The reason I want to do this is because some queries will return a few thousand items, and I have many requests per second running, which could add up (I am running a lower EC2 server on the cloud).

Comment: You could potentially return the entire JSON to the client which can then be parsed on client.

Comment: @HarshalBulsara  Yes this is what I want to do, but how?